# Java, convert between two different generic instances

Tags: java, generics

I want to make an adapter interface (and implementations) to use multiple similar external libraries.

For example, there are interfaces of external libraries. These libraries guide to implement `Converter` and register it to extend features.

Lib A

```
public interface AConverter<S, D> {
    D convert(S source);
}
```

Lib B

```
public interface BConverter<S, D> {
  D convert(S source);
}
```

Both interfaces specify the same method.

What I want is to use my own `MyConverter` interface.

```
public interface MyConverter<S, D> {
  D convert(S source);
}
```

A user implements this class and my library converts the implementation to either LibA's implementation of `AConverter` or LibB's implementation of `BConverter`. Is this possible?

EDIT:

I do not want factory pattern or extends LibA interface and LibB interface. MyConverter is core library, LibA and LibB are external plugable libraries.

What I am trying is,

```
public ALibAdapter {
    AConverter change(MyConverter convert) {
        /**
         * Anything I can do?
         */
        return aConverter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface can extend the existing interfaces:

```
public interface MyConverter<S, D> extends AConverter<S, D>, BConverter<S, D> {
  ...
}
```

You can now use it in place of either one of the library interfaces.

If all methods have the same name (`convert`), they can be overridden. Else you'd have to make sure to call those implementations from your own method using Java 8 default method implementations.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want make and lib dependency in Converter interface.